# Windows 10 Sound level ignored by random applications

Tags: windows-10, audio

Some applications seem to ignore Windows' volume level, sounding way too loud, and resetting to the correct sound after I turn it up or down. It doesn't appear to be defined what applications affect what, but tried and tested so far are: Discord, Firefox, Wallpaper Engine and a few games at random (it works well sometimes, other times it doesn't.)

I tried making sure that the audio driver was updated, not sure if it worked, I installed the most recent available driver from Realtek's site. maybe audio settings?
I currently have the following settings applied:

Speaker volume on 30. No enhancements but with immediate mode turned on. On the Advanced settings page, 24 bit 192000 Hz (Studio Quality), with both exclusive mode options ticked on. *Could that be it?*

I verified that it isn't a hardware issue, and it doesn't seem to be a driver issue either, probably OS' fault, on Linux it works flawlessly.

System Info, in case it may be useful:
I'm running Windows 10 ver 20.04 with build 19041.388

This is the first page in dxdiag, with the system info:

[image: System info tab in dxdiag, excluding time and name]

This is the sound page in dxdiag

[image: Sound page in dxdiag]

Answer (score 0):

Same problem: I start an app, turn volume up using buttons, and volume goes DOWN instead. Haven't done any testing but it's just a big fat annoyance.
Asus Transformer Mini T102
Windows 10 Home V1909 B18363.959
Device Manager > speaker > driver
> Microsoft Intel SST audio device